# Broadcast Receiver is not working on Samsung newer versions of Android

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile

Here is the code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsListener"
        android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Just a simple "SmsListener" as follows:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
```

Also requesting permissions at run time is set as well and application is granted  with required permissions.

```
 if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "android.permission.READ_SMS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

I tested on most of the devices (iOS as well) it works fine but seems Android 6.0 ignores BroadcastReceiver and "onReceive" does not get triggered.

When I change  Default Messaging app from "Messages" to "Hangouts" or "Messenger" then onReceive gets triggered.

[image]

Any idea why Android 6.0 and above acts like this?

Comment: All required permissions are granted to the application but still no result.

Comment: @arlen, although they were granted, you still need to ask user with these permissions.

Comment: I did through the code on my application and still it doesn't work on Android 6.0 and above but when I change Default Messaging app from "Messages" to "Hangouts" or "Messenger" then "onReceive" gets triggered.

Comment: Which device are you changing the default app on? The sender, or the receiver?

Comment: Receiver device, the device which my app is installed.

Comment: Are the devices you're testing on all on the same carrier? If so, which one? T-Mobile, maybe? Or possibly AT&T? Are you certain the messages your app is missing are being delivered as SMS? I.e., when you [query your SMS inbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android), are those missed messages there?

Comment: T-Mobile,  I will try to query Sms inobx to see those messages there or missing and let you know.

Comment: Given that you're on T-Mobile, and the messages don't appear in the SMS Provider, then I would have to guess that they might actually be RCS, which will not fire your SMS Receiver. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044406/sms-missing-from-content-provider-results-on-android-marshmallow

Comment: Seems the problem is Samsung devices with Android 6.0 and above with T-Mobile carrier.