# How to retrieve RCS messages from Android Devices

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, messaging, rich-communications-services

How do i retreive RCS messages in android. I can retreive SMS/MMS using contentproviders, is there any URI for RCS messaging availlable for android?

I found that my device has this contentprovider availlabe so I tried using this :

```
  Uri.parse("content://com.gsma.services.rcs.provider.chat/chatmessage")
```

but this gives me a Security Exception like This :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.sec.internal.ims.servicemodules.tapi.service.provider.ChatProvider from ProcessRecord{31c3db7 9607:com.sol.testsms/u0a403} (pid=9607, uid=10403) requires com.gsma.services.permission.RCS or com.sec.imsservice.WRITE_IMS_PERMISSION
```

after adding the permissions stated in the error message I still get the error.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Question: are you able to send RCS messages? see my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366833/how-to-send-rcs-rich-communication-services-messages-from-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worked only in the device where google messaging is enabled :

RCS message basically is stored in `Uri.parse("content://mms")` content providers.You can alternatively use`Telephony.Mms.CONTENT_URI`.
You can read the RCS related message by passing the  `URI Uri.parse("content://mms")` in the  contentResolver. Actually mms content type read the both mms and RCS message. Sample code is given here.

```
 val cursor = contentResolver.query(
        Uri.parse("content://mms"),
        arrayOf("*"),
        "thread_id = ?",
        selectionArgs,
        null
    )
```

Comment: i tried your approach and was finally able to get some RCS messages in my app. you are a lifesaver.

Comment: Is this how all messaging apps handle it? or is this exclusive to Google's? Does Samsung Messages also simply store the RCS as if it was an MMS message?

Comment: Tested in Samsung , google pixel and xiomi device so far and found that the RCS message  is in MMS . Need to confirm about the other devices

Comment: I wasn't asking about devices, but rather apps themselves. you can use Google's Messages app on any device, but not every device/app that can send and receive RCS is necessarily going to do so in the same way (that is, assuming the system isn't actually the one storing them this way)

Comment: Yes, Samsung messages are not stored in the same way. I updated the answer.

Comment: I am able to receive RCS messages in my SMS app, but I don't know who to send RCS messages. Any clue / link to library or doc?

Comment: are you able to receive RCS messages from any Messaging app ? like samsung messenger ?